# Do I need a visa to transfer flight in Seoul (Incheon Airport)?

Tags: transit, transit-visas, south-korea, chinese-citizens, icn

I'm a Chinese citizen with Japan one-time tourist visa. I booked two tickets to go home, Okinawa to Seoul (Incheon Airport) and Seoul (Incheon Airport) to Dalian.

Do I need a South Korean visa to transfer between my flights?

Comment: @k2moo4 I disagree. The suggested duplicate concerns different circumstances and the answer relies on a dead link contained in the question. It isn't possible to answer this question with the information available at that one.

Answer (score 1):

Per TIMATIC, the database used by airlines;

> TWOV (Transit Without Visa):
>   Visa required, **except** for Passengers transiting through Seoul
>   (ICN) with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third
>   country within 24 hours. They must stay in the international
>   transit area of the airport and have documents required for
>   the next destination.

However, with separate tickets, the check-in staff will likely treat Seoul as your final destination, and thus deny you boarding without a visa.

On what airline is your Naha-Seoul flight? You need to contact the handling agent in Naha for that airline.